# Moving a framed environment to the left

Tags: spacing, lists, color, boxes, framed

I want to move the following remark environment, which nicely splits over pages :), towards the left so that it is not centered anymore. I have been unsuccessfully trying for a while: would you please have suggestions? Thanks. I was thinking of embedding it in a second environment with the required properties?

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[top=7cm,left=5cm,right=5cm,bottom=7cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{framed}
\renewcommand*\FrameCommand{\fcolorbox{red!10}{red!10}}%
\newenvironment{rem}[1][]{%
\MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-10em \FrameRestore}%
\noindent\textsc{#1}%
\small%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.04\textwidth}%
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{0.01\textwidth}%
  }%
    \item[]%
    }{%
    \hfill$\square$%
  \end{list}\endMakeFramed}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[5]
\begin{rem}[Latin]
some random text some random text some random text some random text some random 
text some random text some random text some random text some random text some 
random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some   
random text some random 
\end{rem}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't see anything obvious from looking through the package source. I suggest asking on c.t.t.; Donald Arseneau often answers questions there and he's the best person to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would

```
\renewcommand*\FrameCommand{\hskip-2cm\fcolorbox{red!10}{red!10}}%
```

not do it?

Comment: correct. Very nice !